# Cronjob error: not able to find client_secret.json file Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a python script that daily uploads a file to my Google Drive.  It works perfectly when I run the script from the terminal.  However, when it gets ran through cronjob it fails and returns the following error:

oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory',2)

The problem is that the file is in the directory I am running the script from.

Here is my Cronjob code:

```
15 6 * * * python3 /home/pi/directory/file.py
```

Here is the script that calls the client_secret.json file:

```
def main():
    try:
        import argparse
        flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
        flags = None

    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    store = file.Storage('storage.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
                if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
    DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

Comment: The error says 'Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory'. When it uses cron, it is necessary to be careful about the path of files. So how about the change to the absolute path for the file of client_secret.json? I don't know know whether this will be a solution for you. I'm sorry.

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful for you.

Comment: It was a great idea, bummer it didn't work.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: @Tanaike, actually you were totally right.  I tried it on my PC, but the script was running on my raspberry pi.  Your question made me rethink this and then I realized I didn't update the script on my Raspberry Pi.  Once I did that everything worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm glad to know my comment was useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the absolute path for the file client _secret.json.  Once I updated the path everything worked.

Changed:
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)

and

store = file.Storage('storage.json')

to

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('/path/to/file/client_secret.json', SCOPES)

and

store = file.Storage('/path/to/file/storage.json')